# How to get selected toggle from toggle group?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created one toggle group and now I want to retrieve selected toggle item with some easiest way possible.

[image]

Share your side suggestions with me...

**EDIT:**
Here you have ToggleGroup details:
[image]

I was using this code to check:

```
public class RandomMatchMakerPanelController : MonoBehaviour
{


public Sprite defaultPlayerPhoto;
//
[Header ("Player-1")]
public Image player1Photo;
public Text player1NameText;
public Text player1CountryText;
public ToggleGroup player1BallGroup;

[Header ("Player-2")]
public Image player2Photo;
public Text player2NameText;
public Text player2CountryText;
public ToggleGroup player2BallGroup;

void OnEnable ()
{
//      StartCoroutine (CreateRandomMatches ());
        GetSelectedToggle ();
    ShowLocalPlayerDetails ();
}

private void ShowLocalPlayerDetails ()
{
    if (DataCollection.localPlayer.ProfilePhoto == null)
        player1Photo.sprite = defaultPlayerPhoto;
    else
        player1Photo.sprite = DataCollection.localPlayer.ProfilePhoto;
    player1NameText.text = DataCollection.localPlayer.PlayerName;
    player1CountryText.text = DataCollection.localPlayer.Country;
}

private void GetSelectedToggle ()
{
//      Toggle[] ballToggles = player1BallGroup.GetComponentsInChildren<Toggle> ();
    foreach (Toggle toggle in player1BallGroup.ActiveToggles()) {
        Debug.Log ("toggle: "+ toggle.isOn);
    }
    // May have several selected toggles
//      foreach (Toggle toggle in ballToggles) {
//          if(toggle.isOn)
//      }
}

IEnumerator CreateRandomMatches ()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.25f);
    RandomMatchMaker matchMaker = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag (GameConstants.TAG_NETWORK_MANAGER).GetComponent<RandomMatchMaker> ();
    matchMaker.FindInternetMatch ("Dodgels-");
}

public void OnBackButtonClick ()
{
    SoundManager.Instance.PlayButtonClickSound ();
    Camera.main.SendMessage (GameConstants.ACTIVATE_RANDOM_MATCH_MAKER_PANEL, false, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
    Camera.main.SendMessage (GameConstants.ACTIVATE_RANDOM_PLAYER_GAMEPLAY, false, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
    Camera.main.SendMessage (GameConstants.ACTIVATE_MAIN_MENU_PANEL, true, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
}
}
```

At present nothing get displayed in Console though one toggle at a time remain always active.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @derHugo this is not a trial and check related question - only one answer exist that I was searching ... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute following method from the parent of your toggles

```
Toggle GetSelectedToggle()
{
    Toggle[] toggles=GetComponentsInChildren<Toggle>();
    foreach (var t in toggles)
    if (t.isOn) return t;  //returns selected toggle
    return null;           // if nothing is selected return null
}
```

Comment: Thank you. In my case `ActiveToggles()` not working....
So using `IEnumerable<Toggle> x =  togglegroup.GetComponentsInChildren<Toggle>().Where(t => t.isOn);`

Answer (score 7):

You can get all active toggles with the [`ActiveToggles()` function](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.UI.ToggleGroup.html#UnityEngine_UI_ToggleGroup_ActiveToggles) which selects the set of active toggles in the group. Usually, this set is composed of a unique Toggle.

```
using System.Linq;

// ...

public UnityEngine.UI.ToggleGroup ToggleGroup ; // Drag & drop the desired ToggleGroup in the inspector

private void Start()
{
    if( ToggleGroup == null ) ToggleGroup = GetComponent<ToggleGroup>();
}

public void LogSelectedToggle()
{
    // May have several selected toggles
    foreach( Toggle toggle in ToggleGroup.ActiveToggles() )
    {
         Debug.Log( toggle, toggle ) ;
    }

    // OR

    Toggle selectedToggle = ToggleGroup.ActiveToggles().FirstOrDefault();
    if( selectedToggle != null )
        Debug.Log( selectedToggle, selectedToggle ) ;
}
```

Comment: your above code giving me, compile-time error - "Foreach statement cannot operate on a `method group' "

Comment: That should be easy to fix. ActiveToggles is a function not property. Modified the Hellium's answer to fix that.

Comment: ToggleGroup.ActiveToggles() - this line returning nothing even if one toggle was selected. ToggleGroup.ActiveToggles().FirstOrDefault() - this line is out of my scope

Comment: It works **perfectly fine** here. Make sure your toggles have the toggleGroup specified in the `Group` field, and make sure you have dragged & dropped the toggle group in the `ToggleGroup` of the script.

Comment: I have uploaded more details in question - you can check my code and inspector - still loop not get executed single time...

Comment: Where is called the `foreach` loop? Who calls it? When? Are you sure it's called? Add a `Debug.Log` outside the `foreach` loop to see if the function is correctly called. Are you sure the script is referencing the correct ToggleGroup?

Comment: Full script code uploaded - I have more than 6 years of game development experience and from last 3 years working with Unity - so don't ask a few silly questions - Its reality that its not working so that I am sharing details with you - I am humble that you are trying to help me so thank you for this :)